# Next.js 13 Cookie value not retrieved from Route Handler

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am currently trying to request and receive a cookie value to test the route handler in Next.js 13, but an error occurs.

Even though cookies are normally present in the network window and application, cookies are not retrieved from the Route Handler.

what is the problem ?

- page component

```js
export default async function Home() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessTokenObj = cookieStore.get("accessToken");
  const refreshTokenObj = cookieStore.get("refreshToken");
  const accessToken = accessTokenObj?.value;
  const refreshToken = refreshTokenObj?.value;

  // it works well
  console.log("Page Component refreshToken : ", refreshToken);
  const getTestMessage = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test");

  const data = await getTestMessage.json();

  console.log("getTestMessage : ", data);
```

- app/api/test

```js
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessTokenObj = cookieStore.get("accessToken");
  const refreshTokenObj = cookieStore.get("refreshToken");

  // it doesn't works
  console.log("refreshToken : ", refreshTokenObj);
  const accessToken = accessTokenObj?.value;
  const refreshToken = refreshTokenObj?.value;

  return NextResponse.json({ refreshToken: refreshToken });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you are sending GET request to correct endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this on my machine using this code:

`/app/api/test/route.ts`

```js
'use server'

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessTokenObj = cookieStore.get("accessToken");
  const refreshTokenObj = cookieStore.get("refreshToken");

  // it doesn't works
  console.log("refreshToken : ", refreshTokenObj);
  const accessToken = accessTokenObj?.value;
  const refreshToken = refreshTokenObj?.value;

  return NextResponse.json({ refreshToken: refreshToken });
}
```

Make sure to update your `next.config.js` to enable the experimental 'use server'.

```js
experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
```

for example:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

In your front-end component, you have to pass the cookie values. I'm not sure why, but for some reason the Nextjs fetch is not sending the cookie data by default.

```js
  const getTestMessage = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test",
    {
      cache: 'no-store',
      headers: { cookie: `accessToken=${accessToken}; refreshToken=${refreshToken}` }
    });
```

Comment: It still occurs same problem, Although I deleted .next folder and restart npm run dev...

Comment: I just updated the response to pass in the cookie values in your component. See the updated answer.