# Next.JS 13.4 Cookies() Function Works In Route Handler In Development But Not Production

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js13, ruby-on-rails-7

This seems to be touched on in this question [Next.js 13 Cookie value not retrieved from Route Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879784/next-js-13-cookie-value-not-retrieved-from-route-handler), but the answer there isn't working for me.

I have a Nextjs 13.4 frontend and a Rails 7 API-only backend with Doorkeeper configured to authenticate with an HTTP-Only cookie.

I've implemented Next.js Route Handlers to make API calls to the backend that need to include the cookie for create/update/delete routes.

In development, working with localhost:3000 on the front and localhost:3001 on the back, I can retrieve the access_token cookie from the browser using either the Next.js `cookies()` function or with the Request object via `req.cookies()` function and pass it along to the Rails API request.

However, when I'm in production, where I have the Next.js app hosted on Netlify and the backend hosted on Heroku (cross-origin), both cookies functions return an empty object, even though I can see the access_token stored correctly in the browser using devTools.

In production the cookie is set as Secure, sameSite=None and HttpOnly, which should allow for cross-origin sharing. Both apps communicate via https. I've spent days now trying to get this to work and I'm starting to think it's a bug in Next.js, but maybe someone with more knowledge on this subject than me might see an issue with my code below.

Following the path of an update form submission, I first make a fetch call from the update form, a client component, to the `PUT` route handler. I'm including credentials in the fetch request, which by my understanding should send the cookies along in the request object:

`form.component.tsx`

```
// handlers
  const submitHandler: SubmitHandler<ProductFormData> = async (
    formData: ProductFormData
  ) => {
    setLoading(true);

    // format form data for fetch request
    const encodedData = encodeProductFormData(formData, defaultImage, images);

    try {
      // update
      if (product) { 
        const response = await fetch(`/api/products/${ product.slug }`, {
          credentials: 'include',
          method: 'PUT',
          body: encodedData
        });
      } else { 
        // create
        const response = await fetch('/api/products', {
          credentials: 'include',
          method: 'POST',
          body: encodedData
        });
      }

      router.push('/');
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.error('Something went wrong:', error);
    }
  };
```

That request comes through to the `PUT` route handler, where I need to extract the `access_token` cookie from either the request object or the `cookies()` function. As you can see below, I am using `request.cookies.get('access_token')`. In development, this works perfectly. The cookie is retrieved and sent correctly to the `updateProduct()` API call to the external Rails server. In production, if I console log the request object, I can see that the cookies are empty, even though the `access_token` is present and correctly set in the browser.

`/api/products/[slug]/route.ts`

```
export const PUT = async (
  request: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { slug: string } } 
) => {
  // extract doorkeeper auth token from cookies
  const token = request.cookies.get('access_token');

  // get slug from params
  const slug = params.slug;

  // get form data from request
  const formData = await request.formData();

  // send to /v1/products#update endpoint
  const product = await updateProduct(slug, formData, token);

  // configure response
  const response = NextResponse.json(
    { product: product },
    { status: 200 }
  );

  // refresh data & router cache
  revalidatePath('/');

  return response;
};
```

I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working in production. What might I be missing here that could be preventing cookies from getting passed to the route handler?

The cookies DO get sent if I make a direct call from the form to the Rails backend, but then I can't call revalidatePath and refresh the cache, so the changes don't get updated on the frontend because of Next.js' frustrating caching system.